# How to request view to show dialog and get result from WPF/MVVM model?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a C#/WPF app. There is a task running lengthy operations and it needs a way to show a dialog requesting users decision at some point. The task can't exit and be restarted. It needs to remain paused and wait for the dialog result. There are plenty ways to do it. How do I do it properly in MVVM? How do I request users interaction from business logic?

Comment: Post your code if you can, no one is getting paid to solve anyone elses problems so please make it as easy as possible to answer your question.

Comment: Lloyd, I am not asking for code, rather for general direction which way to go.

Comment: Generally the long running operation will be in a worker thread, so as not to freeze the UI. It would need to call a function in the UI thread to display a dialog. There's nothing particular about MVVM here.

Comment: This depends on how the code is setup, which is why I asked for context. I don't like large texts of explanations, I'd rather see where the code has to fit in.

Comment: I use a service, that has a reference to a custom Window. View Model hasn't got access to any kind of window, just a service, you could even do IoC and just use an interface. This way I have my separation of concerns. FYI use dispatcher at service side so you don't have to worry about thread safety.

Answer (score 0):

It highly depends on what you want to achieve and how your code is set up.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/dialog-boxes-overview That is a great article about the built in dialogue boxes that comes with WPF, you can also create your own.

Comment: Thanks. I was rather asking how to make the view show the dialog (and get the result) from model's code (or a running task)

Comment: Happy to help !

Answer (score 0):

I have a separate dll for services. In there there is a `MessageBoxService`.
That service references a Window. I'll leave the implementation up to you.
My Service implements an interface to be injectable, it isn't but just in case it can be.
Here is the snippet of what it provides:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace Services.MessageBox
{
    public class MessageBoxService : IMessageBoxService
    {
        Dispatcher dispatcher;
        private Window mainWindow;

        public MessageBoxService()
        {
            dispatcher = Application.Current.Dispatcher;
            mainWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow;
        }

        private void UIThread(Action execute)
        {
            dispatcher.Invoke(execute);
        }

        public void Show(string caption, string message)
        {
            UIThread(() =>
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(mainWindow, message, caption, System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.OK);
            });
        }

        public bool? ShowDialog(string caption, string message)
        {
            bool? result = null;

            UIThread(() =>
            {
                result = new Windows.Modal(message, caption).ShowDialog(mainWindow);
            });

            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you would use it like this in your ViewModel:

```
var answer = messageBoxService.ShowDialog("Title Here", "Message to display");
```